# JQuery .remove() not removing paragraph by id

Tags: jquery

I have something like this in the body of my HTML:

```
<p id="test.txt"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disp">test.txt</a> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del">x</a>]</p>
<p id="test2.txt"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disp">test2.txt</a> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del">x</a>]</p>
<p id="test3.txt"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disp">test3.txt</a> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del">x</a>]</p>
<p id="test4.txt"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disp">test4.txt</a> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del">x</a>]</p>
<p id="test5.txt"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disp">test5.txt</a> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del">x</a>]</p>
<p id="test6.txt"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disp">test6.txt</a> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del">x</a>]</p>
```

This is part of the relevant JQuery code:

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
    if (myClass==="del"){
        var idToDelete = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        alert(idToDelete);
        $("#" + idToDelete).remove();
        return;
    }
})
```

When clicking one of the links, it seems to correctly get the ID, however, the paragraph is not removed from the page. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to escape the period, otherwise jQuery is looking for an element with the `id` of `test1` and a class of `txt` or you could just use `closest ('p')`.

Comment: yep, jQuery is looking for an id `test` which has class `txt` =>`$("#text.txt")`

Comment: you can also use `$(this).parent().remove()` directly I think, as Satpal said

Comment: that bit of code stops all links on your site working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can traverse to element to remove, Just use

```
 $(this).parent().remove();
```

The reason `$("#" + idToDelete).remove();` is not working as there is a meta character `.` in `idToDelete` which needs to be escaped with `\\`.

Note, You code can be improve as

```
$('a.del').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! I knew it was something silly I was doing. I also took your advice and used the a.del selector in Jquery. Thank you so much!